# How can I setup Redis Cluster mode or master slave mode in PCF?

Tags: redis, cloud-foundry, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster, pcf

This is regarding the use case where we are trying to use the Redis in PCF (Pivotal Cloud Foundry). In our use case, we will refresh the Redis cache daily once or twice with the required data and then API will query Redis and then provide the response.

One thing of particular concern for us is that we want API queries to happen from Redis only that means Redis to be available at all times. But whenever we are refreshing the Redis DB, Redis would not be able to serve the APIs since it is refreshing the keys. To avoid that we wanted to setup a Redis in cluster mode or master-slave mode so if one instance is being written another can be read from.

How can we setup Redis cluster or master-slave mode in PCF and then fulfil our requirement?
Please provide any other suggestions as well that you may have.

Answer (score 0):

At the time I write this, the Redis for Pivotal Platform product does not support clustering. See Availability, in the docs here -> https://docs.pivotal.io/redis/2-3/erc.html#offerings.

> All Redis for Pivotal Platform services are single VMs without clustering capabilities. This means that planned maintenance jobs (e.g., upgrades) can result in 2–10 minutes of downtime, depending on the nature of the upgrade. Unplanned downtime (e.g., VM failure) also affects the Redis service.
>
> Redis for Pivotal Platform has been used successfully in enterprise-ready apps that can tolerate downtime. Pre-existing data is not lost during downtime with the default persistence configuration. Successful apps include those where the downtime is passively handled or where the app handles failover logic.

If you require clustered Redis, you'd need to look at a different offering. Redis Labs has [some offerings that integrate with PCF](https://network.pivotal.io/products/redis-enterprise-pack/info), you could use a Cloud Provider's Redis offering, or you could host your own.

If the solution you use isn't integrated into PCF, you can create a user-provided service with `cf cups` and provide the Redis credentials to your application that way. It will function just like a Redis service instance created through the marketplace.